# Do I use the word "which" or "what"

Tags: word-choice

> **What** is the principle circulating sugar in the blood and is the major energy source of the body?

Comment: I think you mean "principal".

Comment: "Which" is only possible if there is more than one kind of circulating sugar, where it is used to select an item from a subset of items. Otherwise, use "what".

Answer (score 0):

**What** is generally used for questions where the possibilities are open, not chosen from some limited set. "**What** is the flight speed of an unladen swallow?"

**Which**, in a question, is used where *what* might be used, but there is some finite, well understood set of options. "The meals available tonight are steak, lasagne, or vegetable stew. **Which** would you like?"

In this case, either are possible, because there is a limited range of naturally-occurring sugars. However, it's quite a large range, so unless the set of sugars had been narrowed down in preceding text, I would personally tend to use **what**.